# How Many Negative Eigenvalues of $-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}$ on $[0,L]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series, spectral-theory

What is the maximum number of eigenvalues $\lambda < 0$ for the trigonometric problems?:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
                        -\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}}=\lambda f,\\
                        \cos\alpha f(0) + \sin\alpha f'(0) = 0,\\
                        \cos\beta f(L)+\sin\beta f'(L)=0,
\end{array}
$$
where $0 \le \alpha,\beta < \pi$ are allowed to vary.

**Example:** If $\alpha = \beta \in (0,\pi/2)\cup(\pi/2,\pi)$, there is **one negative eigenvalue** $\lambda=-\cot^{2}(\alpha)$ with non-normalized eigenfunction
$e^{-(\cot(\alpha))x}$. This gives rise to an unusual complete orthogonal basis of eigenfunctions for $L^{2}[0,L]$:
$$
   \exp\left\{-x\cot(\alpha)\right\},\sin\alpha \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)
         -\cos\alpha\frac{L}{n\pi}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right),\;\; n =1,2,3,\cdots\;.
$$
When properly normalized, these eigenfunctions form a complete orthonormal basis of $[0,L]$. In other cases, there can be more than one negative eigenvalue.

Comment: There can be at most two negative eigenvalues. This is treated in detail in section 4.3 of the PDE book by Strauss. In his notation, the boundary conditions are $f'(0)-a_0 f(0)=0$ and $f'(L)+a_Lf(L)=0$. The hyperbola $a_0+a_L=-a_0a_L L$  divides the plane into three regions, corresponding to $0,1,2$ negative eigenvalues. (On the hyperbola, there is a zero eigenvalue.)

Comment: @Thursday : Thank you! I was having trouble finding a full treatment of this classical problem.